# Amazon SQS queue: getting a response from queue

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

**Image processing system.**

User uploads a photo to the S3. Image processing application takes the photo from S3 and starts processing on it and returns an output.

**Process:**
Webserver is sending SQS message with info of image to the queue, and the Image processing Server gets the SQS message and starts processing over this image. As soon as the image processing is finished it uploads the image back to S3 and returns the SQS message back to queue. Image Processing engine is on the EC2 server.

Here is the question:
How can the webserver get the return SQS message from queue which was sent from Image processing server?

Answer (score 7):

Don't think of image processing as a remote procedure call, where there's a request and a response -- think of it as a series of tasks being performed by the different components in your distributed system. Solve this problem with two queues: `uploaded-images` and `processed-images`.

A web server accepts the image, puts it in S3, and posts a message to the `uploaded-images` queue indicating that it needs to be processed.

Your image processing EC2 instances wait for messages to arrive on the `uploaded-images` queue, then retrieve the image from S3, do some processing, and put the results in S3. They then send a message to the `processed-images` queue indicating that the image has been processed.

Your web servers poll `processed-images`, and do whatever they need to do once an image is processed: update a database, set an entry in a short-lived cache indicating the image is done processing, etc.

Comment: Great answer, but how can the webserver retrieve the messages from processed-images queue, as well the image processing server from uploaded-images queue? I'm using php, and I can write the message to the uploaded-images, but how can I get the message from the processed-images queue? Can you provie with sample code?

Comment: Well, a normal answer would be to run a background thread or worker process, both of which could be problematic for PHP. If your "upload" page goes to a page where the user waits for their image to be processed, you could poll `processed-images` there -- just bear in mind that you might be handling processed images besides the one you just uploaded. It's hard to give specific advice on that without knowing more about what the web server is doing.

Comment: can you give me you skype or gmail account so that I can relay the issue in more detail. thanx

Comment: Willglynn can you provide a piece of code for polling from processed-images queue, in sample example or any other link for this kind of issue?

Comment: @ssd In PHP, your options are a little more limited about how to poll the processed-images queue.  You could run a cron job once per minute to process the queue is that 1+min lag in knowing that the process is completed is OK for you. You could conceivably also have a long running process (i.e infinite loop with timeouts between queue checks) that checks the queue more frequently, that is perhaps checked to see if running by cron and restarted if the process terminated for some reason. That could be problematic though if you have any memory leaks.

Comment: @Mike Brant, thank you for for your answer. I'm about to check the status of the uploaded images in every 3-5 seconds, because processing ends in 3 seconds. About 50-60 thousand of users visits the site every day, and I need to take care about the  performance of the webserver.  Let's say one user tries one image, so there will be 60 thousands of messages in queue.  Don't you think that it could lead to the server down?

Comment: @ssd How many image uploads do you get per day (or expect to get per day)? that is the metric that should really matter with regards to capacity planning.  The queue size itself should not be the problem.  What is unclear here is exactly what your usage pattern is.  Do you need to provide some sort of near-immediate feedback to the user that this processing is completed, or is the processing something that is simply on your end without there knowledge? Do you even need a message to signify completion of the process, or could some record in a database simply be updated when processing is done?